# How to change the batch size when model conversion?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

```
2019-04-19 09:53:07.409720: F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1449] Check failed: batch == 1 (128 vs. 1)
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x00007f39d5ad9700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 33 in execute
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300 in run
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40 in run
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 59 in main
  File "/home/yuchen/anaconda2/envs/tryTF/bin/toco_from_protos", line 10 in <module>
Aborted (core dumped)
```

_____________error message is above_________________

> I try to convert a tf(.pb) model to a tflite(.tflite) model. It seems
>   that the converter will only accept batch_size==1 and it can't
>   automatically change the batch_size from 128(my training batch) to 1.

Both of Batch_size 1 and 128 are tried, but they don't work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
convert= tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph("frozen.pb",input_arrays=["Placeholder_2"],output_arrays=["l2_normalize"],input_shapes={"Placeholder_2":[128, 100, 129]})
tflite_model=convert.convert()
open("model.tflite","wb").write(tflite_model)
```

How to change the batch size to 1